# Load a second div when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The purpose of this code was to populate a div from a PHP file when a button is clicked. 
Also to pre populate a div when page loads - I have completed this task.

Now I want to load a second div at the same time and I'm unsure how to go about this.

```
function loadpage(clicked_id) {
  if (clicked_id != 0 || clicked_id != null || clicked_id !="") {
    $("#Table").load("marshfight1.php?action=fight&id="+ clicked_id);
    $("#mobs").load("marshtab.php");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // initial
  $('#mobs').load('marshtab.php');
});

Echo "<div id=Table></div>";
Echo "<div id=mobs></div>";

$selem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM senemies WHERE userid='$playerinfo[id]' && arena='10'");
while($enem = mysql_fetch_array($selem)) {
  Echo "<button><type=button id=\"$enem[id]\" onclick=\"loadpage(this.id)\" name=\"$enem[id]\">$enem[name]<br>Level: $enem[level]<br> HP: $enem[hp]</a></button>";
}
```

Everything works fine except for the second .load to update #mobs.

Comment: you can't just mix and match PHP and JavaScript, PHP is executed server-side, while JavaScript is executed client-side.

Comment: First thing you're doing wrong is not indenting your code properly.  :P

Comment: This successfully works, its just not re updating the second DIV

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the inclusion of PHP in your javascript.  Remember that though PHP will throw a compile error, IE will do its best and FF will do its best up to the point of the error then very quietly quit.  Thus it will appear to be working but actually half your code never gets executed.  ctrl-shift-k in FF will give you a rundown of errors.

What you need is ajax.  This is easy to implement in both jquery and 'straight' javascript.

Forgive me if you already know this, but others use this forum so a brief summary of the process would be:

1. Button is clicked triggering JS onclick function.
2. onclick function sends appropriate data (which button for instance and/or usernumber etc) to php file.
3. onclick function puts whatever the php returns in the div as desired.

You need to get your js and php organised and separated.

A good overview and basic tutorial can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/